# Change background image of a fixed div depending on other scrollabe divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change the background image of .fixedIcon depending on the scrollable div that is visible on the screen. For instance if a user is reading div1, I want the background image of .fixedIcon to be icon1.gif, and when the user continues to div2 I want to change the background image to icon2.gif etc etc.... How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

Here is the CSS file:

```
.fixedIcon {
z-index: -1;
background-image: url('');
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
position: fixed;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

And here is the Html page:

```
<div class="fixedIcon"></div>
<div id=1">Long text</div>
<div id=2">Long text</div>
<div id=3">Long text</div>
<div id=4">Long text</div>
```

Comment: What is your attempt to create this yourself? I don't see any jQuery code

Comment: Why to post the attempt if it's wrong?

Comment: It might be something very small that is the problem and it's a good way to learn what mistake you made, and second StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I'm still a beginner and that's why I'm here. Sorry to bother you....

Answer (score 0):

`document.documentElement.scrollTop` gives you the scroll distance from the top.

`document.getElementById('sampleId').offsetTop` gives you the distance from the top to that element

`window.onscroll` can add event listener to scroll event. (You can optimize it by fire it once in a given interval)

The solution is to add event listener to `scroll` and get the value of scroll distance from the top.
After that, compare this value to your div distance from top and decide whether you need to change you background image or not.